# A new kind of cipher?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

So,
I believe that I may have created a new kind of cipher, would you be able to solve it? (I'll let you know what I've decided to name it once you've solved it :) )

> `a r r
>        n c r
>        l b e
>        g a o
> l a b  y s e  o e l
> t t w  o s i  u z n
>        u a o
>        s e g`

Hint:

> If you are looking at this 2 dimensionally, you are going about it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we follow the clue from the comments, and

> Break the image into six parts, each representing the face of a rectangular prism, we get: 
>  a r r 
>  n c r 
>  l b e 
>  g a o 
>  l a b 
>  t t w 
>  y s e 
>  o s i 
>  o e l 
>  u z n 
>  u a o 
>  s e g

Then, if we take

> the top left characters first, followed by the top middle characters, etc. we get: allyourbasearebelongtouscatszerowing.

This, when adding spaces and punctuation, gives the quote (and popular Internet meme, apparently):

> "All your base are belong to us." -CATS (Zero Wing)

Comment: You got it! I've decided to name this a cubic cipher, and it only works if the total characters are divisible by six. So you can have a 36 character message, a 54 character based message, etc.

Comment: Oh that's really cool! I like it -- have you thought about the order of the cube faces? Could that possibly change/be encoded to make it more difficult?

Comment: Of course! I wanted to do a default one first though. Originally, I played with a rubics cube that I imagined had letters on it. And so you'd give your partner the key, based on rubics cube designs, like the striped design, or the center is different, etc.

Comment: That's awesome! I really like it, and it definitely sounds really versatile as well! :D

Answer (score 3):

This looks like

> the net of a cube. But with all of the letters in the puzzle oriented the same way, it's hard to see what the intended layout is when folding the letters into a cube. I haven't found a way that makes sense yet.

Comment: Oh crap! I didn't think about that... Imagine each represents top left, then top middle, etc.