# What am I cooking up today?

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme

Today,
I decided to cook something that, if it cooks correctly, should turn out pretty cool. Below are a series of riddles and ciphers that list the ingredients for what I am cooking. Can you figure out the ingredients and tell me what it is I am making?

> 1.
> Careful with contents,
> So I change what it looks like,
> Sophistic accents.
>
> 2.
> Here is the most basic component,
> To disclude it makes me impotent.
> Making up the bulk of the recipe
> Look up to me as a neccessity.
>
> 3.
> aoswaqsoepfcisuwudijrthehlmnaihoralacvpafytnkhatdjiyee
> 3x3_grid^3, 9nBlock
>
> 4.
> Please pick peppers From the pepper person, please
> He'll huff and huff; However, he'll heed Our howls.
> Poor Patrick plays powerfully and only gets paid peas.
>
> 5.
> Sacrifice a hand for a large reveal, which turned out to be for the best.
> Quit quivering and hold your ground. To survive in this fort is the real test.
> Look to the clown that never frowns to see the city come together and win.

For your answer to be accepted, you'll have to explain all of the ingredients, though I encourage partial answers.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie, Some have one, others have more than one

Comment: @hagfy, sorry, stupid typos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel like you're probably making

> A website?

Not sure I can explain all the ingredients/clues, but here's an attempt.  First of all

> The acrostics are
> 1-CSS
> 2-HTML
> 4-PHP
> 5-SQL

1.
Careful with contents,
So I change what it looks like,
Sophistic accents.

> This seems to describe Cascading Style Sheets (CSS), used to customize the appearance of a page

2.
Here is the most basic component,
To disclude it makes me impotent.
Making up the bulk of the recipe
Look up to me as a neccessity.

> Again, this seems to describe Hypertext Markup Language (HTML), which is kind of the basis for a web page

3.
aoswaqsoepfcisuwudijrthehlmnaihoralacvpafytnkhatdjiyee
3x3_grid^3, 9nBlock

> Decoding this using [a certain kind of cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70274/a-new-kind-of-cipher) results in:
> **A pinch of JavaScript with a dash of jQuery is what you'll need make**
> JavaScript can be used to execute code embedded in HTML, and jQuery is a JavaScript library.

4.
Please pick peppers From the pepper person, please
He'll huff and huff; However, he'll heed Our howls.
Poor Patrick plays powerfully and only gets paid peas.

> PHP is another scripting language used for web development.
> It seems the alliteration serves to emphasize the acrostic?  Thanks to @Mohirl and @Cashbee for the nudges

5.
Sacrifice a hand for a large reveal, which turned out to be for the best.

> The Empire Strikes Back.  Totally *spaced* on that one.

Quit quivering and hold your ground. To survive in this fort is the real test.

> Based off the hints, guessing this would be a Lord of the Rings movie.  And judging by the other answers, it would be The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers.

Look to the clown that never frowns to see the city come together and win.

> The Dark Knight?

That would mean the answers to the above are all

> movie sequels.
> Structured Query Language (SQL) is used to extract data from a database.
> Many people use SQL as an acronym (as opposed to just an initialism), pronounced 'sequel', hence the connection to the film sequels.
> There's also an uppercase 'T' in the paragraph, so maybe it's specifically using T-SQL to connect to a SQL Server database?  Could just be my work seeping in, though...

Comment: You've got everything correct so far. For number five, I would think about what each line is describing. For number four, think about what's in each line. Just a little more, and you'll have everything! :D

Comment: For #4, rot13(Gur CUC npebfgvp vf ercrngrq zhygvcyr gvzrf)

Comment: @Mohirl, you've got that right! As for clue five, each line refers to a separate movie. If you can figure that out hagfy, I'm sure that you'll finish this puzzle :)

Comment: For the first film, perhaps a certain 1977 sci-fi classic everyone knows?

Comment: You got the last movie correct, the other two think more traditional space fantasy and regular fantasy. Each of the movies shares one thing in common.

Comment: Thanks @EightAndAHalfTails.  I went for the 1980 one though...felt it fit better.  I'm still mulling over the middle one (stupid work always distracting me from important puzzle-solving).

Comment: You've got the first movie right now. The middle one should mention something better, like the elf and the dwarf make a bet, or something like that. The real question is how those movies tie into the clue.

Comment: Oh, I see, the films all share a characteristic that is homophonic to (a certain pronunciation of) the language in question - That should make it obvious what the films are as well.

Comment: @EightAndAHalfTails Indeed!  Despite reading it in my head that way every single time, I didn't make the connection to the actual word.  Realized it on the drive to work this morning...thanks!

Comment: @hagfy, you got it all right! I'll accept it right away!

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Thanks!  Appreciate the patience while I slogged my way through.  I'd give you a ruby medal for this puzzle, and rate my efforts a solid C++.