# You'll be stuck in this maze, forever (Cubic Cipher)!

Tags: riddle, cipher, rhyme, rubiks-cube

Okay, so I mentioned in another puzzle that I created a new kind of cipher, which I refer to as a [Cubic Cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70274/a-new-kind-of-cipher), now that the way to solve it has been established, it's time to ramp things up. As mentioned in the comments of that puzzle, the original idea was to use a Rubik's Cube to solve the cipher based on the patterns that I give in a clue. Here's my attempt at doing so (Please note, this was really difficult for me to create, so I can't guarantee that it's 100% foolproof. I made this one as simple as possible),

Here is the cube, remember each quadrant starts with what would be the top left of it. The order is white, green, red, blue, orange, yellow.

> [image: Rubik's Cipher]

Here is the riddle on how to solve it

> You thought this would be topsy-turvy? Think again!
>   It's a slide we are after. You can do it twice then.
>
> The front, the sides, and the back we are after.
>   The top and bottom rows, we'll spin them faster.
>
> Colors will blur together, green and blue,
>   Orange and red, let us not forget, will too.
>
> Combine these clues to find the message waiting for you.

---

<sub>I'd love some feedback on this puzzle. This one maybe easy, but it's also a test to see how well it'll do here. Any input is encouraged.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is:

> super mario rpg it the only one just for me when i play the game i win

Looking at the riddle,

You thought this would be topsy-turvy? Think again!
It's a slide we are after. You can do it twice then.

> This tells me that the rows will have to be turned twice.

The front, the sides, and the back we are after.
The top and bottom rows, we'll spin them faster.

> The top and the bottom row must be turned, as we are looking for the answer from the front, back, and sides

Colors will blur together, green and blue,
Orange and red, let us not forget, will too.

> If you twist the top and the bottom rows, green and blue will blur together, and so will orange and red!

Putting the cipher into cubes:

> s a g 
>  o e o 
>   e y m 
>  
>    e o t 
>   n j r 
>   p e w  
>  
>   r r h 
>   l u m  
>  l g i  
>  
>   u r i 
>   y s e  
>  n t e  
>   
>  p i t 
>   o t w  
>  i h i  
>  
>   m p e  
>  n f h  
>  a a n

Applying the riddle,

> Turning the top and bottom rows twice:
>  s a g 
>  o e o 
>  e y m
> u r i
> n j r
> n t e
> p i t
> l u m
> i h i
> e o t
> y s e
> p e w
> r r h
> o t w
> l g i
> m p e
> n f h
> a a n

Using what @El-Guest said on your last puzzle:

> the top left characters first, followed by the top middle characters, etc. gives us: supermariorpgittheonlyonejustformewheniplaythegameiwin

Adding spacing gives:

> super mario rpg it the only one just for me when i play the game i win

Comment: Would you explain your answer?

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Just edited!

Comment: Very nice! Well done! What did you think of the puzzle?

Comment: Very well made and quite enjoyable! I'll be looking forward to more of these!